# PowerBI - Row calculation for many to one table in a direct query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, directquery

I have the following two tables - App and App Role joined on 'ApplicationID'. There exists only one ApplicationID row in App table but multiple ApplicationIDS can exists in App Role table.

**Application table:**

Application ID | Tbed | New_Existing |

1234 | 5 | New

234| 10| Existing

**App Role Table**

ApplicationID | App Type | Role

1234| Individual| GC

1234| Org|GC

1234|Org| PB

1234|Individual|GC

234| Individual | PB

**DAX'S I tried:**

Level 1 =
IF(
'App'[TBUS] <= 24 &&  (**TRUE**)
'App'[NE] = "Existing",  (**TRUE**)
IF(
SUMX(FILTER('Application Role', 'App Role'[Role] = "PB"(**TRUE**) && 'App Role[App Type] = "Individual" (FALSE),1)>0,
1,
0
),
0
)0
)

I have tried SUMX, MAXX, COUNTROWS. In the above example: the formula should return false for 1234 because  App type = Individual (True) and the corresponding value of App Role= "PB" is False(0) but I get "1".

Any reviews or recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for PBIX. I assumed you had a relationship between the two tables.

If you do define a relationship on App ID column then you can use:

```
Level 1a = IF(
  ('App'[Total] <= 24) && ('App'[App Purpose] = "Purchase" || 'App'[App Purpose] ="Refinance"),
  IF(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('App Role'), 'App Role'[Applicant Type]= "Individual" && 'App Role'[Role] = "PB") > 0  ,1,0),0)
```

Otherwise without the relationship, you could use:

```
Level 1b = 
  var meId = [App ID]
  var cRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('App Role'), 'App Role'[App ID] = meId && 'App Role'[Applicant Type]= "Individual" && 'App Role'[Role] = "PB")
  var result = IF(('App'[Total] <= 24) && ('App'[App Purpose] = "Purchase" || 'App'[App Purpose] ="Refinance"), cRows)
  RETURN IF(result > 0, 1, 0)
```

Do split your logic like above, helps for readability.

[image]

Comment: The formula gives me a syntax error. I have attached a sample PBIX file, Refer to App ID 914, The result of Level 1 should be 0 but I get 1. 
App(one) and App role(many)  have a many to one relationship where App can filter App role. 
https://github.com/khushs9966/SampleAnalysis/blob/main/test.pbix

Comment: I've updated the answer since seeing the PBIX - thanks for sharing.

Comment: I have updated the relationships on the pbix file. I get an error when I use Level 1a formula.  Can you please take a look?

Comment: I have two formula (Level 1 and Level 2 (On the same columns), I get circular dependency error. How do I resolve them?

Comment: Jump down to the "Circular dependencies in calculated columns" section in this excellent article - https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/

Comment: Great share, Thank you. this helped resolve my circular dependency error. I appreciate it.